# Autocomplete time input for jquery mobile, or different solution

Tags: jquery, html, validation, mobile, timepicker

Ok i hope the title explains enough as i find it difficult to formulate a good question about this.

In short, does a jquery/javascript plugin like this exist:  A textbox where the user can input hours and minutes like so "16:35", but if a user for example types only "16" it automatically writes it as "16:00" when the focus is changed. Also general validation would be nice like only numerical characters allowed etc.

It seems like a trivial problem but i can not really find any ready made solution.

Side note:  Actually, i am making a mobile website using jquery mobile, and after trying many different datepickers and timepickers (android and ios look-a-likes etc) but most have low compatibility so i will try to use the method described above. If you guys have any other solutions they would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

```
$(function() {

    var availableTags = [

        "ActionScript",

        "AppleScript",

        "Asp",

        "BASIC",

        "C",

        "C++",

        "Clojure",

        "COBOL",

        "ColdFusion",

        "Erlang",

        "Fortran",

        "Groovy",

        "Haskell",

        "Java",

        "JavaScript",

        "Lisp",

        "Perl",

        "PHP",

        "Python",

        "Ruby",

        "Scala",

        "Scheme"

    ];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({

        source: availableTags

    });

});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah i saw that, but it doesnt seem very suitable for inputting time. Or?

Comment: This way will give you a string back. Is that what you dont want? There is a convert string time to dateTime on this site. http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?123460-Convert-string-to-time.